# Back link in the view should change according to controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi from Rails novice.

I have a one-to-many model document-chapters.

The **/chapters/new.html.erb** view can be invoked from:

- **/document/:id** (clicking on new chapter link with param document id)
- **/chapters/** (clicking on new chapter link without param document id)

The view has a Back link. When the request come from document I want Back points to **document/:id/show**, when the request come from chapters/index, I want Back points to **chapter/index**.

I can easily implement the logic inside the view, but I would like to know from Rails experts what could be the best solution for this use case, as normally they always suggest to separate the logic from the view.

I'm developing on Rails 4.

Maybe this is a simply totally wrong approach where the best solution is to have two views getting what is common from a partial?

Thanks

Comment: Your use of A & B makes the question confusing to understand.  Eg, what which record would be shown in the "show" action?  Can you change it to more realistic examples?

Comment: Updated to a more realistc example. Hope is more meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you click a link on either the document show page or chapters index to get to the new chapter route?

If you use a back symbol with `link_to` it will use the referrer so you should be able to just use

```
<%= link_to 'Back', :back %>
```

Comment: Ok, it was a simple over-complicated question (novice typical) with a simple answer. Thank you for sharing your expertise.

Comment: No worries, that's what SO is for.  One thing to consider though, if you have validation and it fails and in your `create` action you have `render :new` if it fails then I think (can't remember for certain), then the link to back would go back to the new action not the one that you got to the new action with.